# Edit script to email output?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, terminal, command

I'm basically trying to put two scripts I found online together. The first, in two parts, checks if a directory exists, if not creates it then goes on to take a picture through the webcam if an incorrect login password is entered. As far as I can tell, this part is working properly.

```
#!/bin/bash

## Variables
dir=/tmp/gotcha
got=/tmp/gotcha/gotcha.jpg
SMTPFROM=xxxxx@xxxxx.com
SMTPTO=xxxxx@xxxxx.com
SMTPSERVER=smtp.googlemail.com:587
SMTPUSER=xxxxx@xxxxx.com
SMTPPASS=xxxxx
SUBJECT="Someone tried to access your computer while you were away."

if test [ -d  "$dir" ]
then 
    echo "Found directory /tmp/gotcha/" ]
else 
    mkdir /tmp/gotcha/
fi

ts=`date +%s`
ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -s vga -i /dev/video0 -vframes 1 $got
exit 0  ## NOTE - must exit with status 0
```

The second is SUPPOSED to email me the photo taken, then delete the photo from the storage directory, but as far as I can tell it's not finding the photo even though i can find the file in question through both the command line and the GUI.

```
## sendEmail script, found in /home/josh/scripts/emailscript
if test -f [ "$got" ]
then
        sendemail -f $SMTPFROM -t $SMTPTO -u $SUBJECT -a $got -s $SMTPSERVER -$
fi

## Remove gotcha.jpg
if test -f [ "$got" ]
then
       rm $got
```

When I run the script in the terminal, this is the output:

```
/usr/local/bin/gotcha: line 13: test: too many arguments
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/tmp/gotcha/’: File exists
ffmpeg version 3.4.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.18.04.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  WARNING: library configuration mismatch
  avcodec     configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.18.04.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared --enable-version3 --disable-doc --disable-programs --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libtesseract --enable-libvo_amrwbenc
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
Input #0, video4linux2,v4l2, from '/dev/video0':
  Duration: N/A, start: 10364.818498, bitrate: 147456 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (YUY2 / 0x32595559), yuyv422, 640x480, 147456 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo (native) -> mjpeg (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[swscaler @ 0x558898563320] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
Output #0, image2, to '/tmp/gotcha/gotcha.jpg':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p(pc), 640x480, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.107.100 mjpeg
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/200000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=5.7 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:00.03 bitrate=N/A speed=3.32x    
video:24kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
```

Like I said, I'm new to bash scripting, so I'm probably overlooking something silly, but any help is appreciated!

Comment: I guess second script is a partial copy/paste as `if` is unclosed.

Comment: Didn't even notice theif/them for rm wasn't closed. Thanks, but for some reason the file still isn't being removed.

Comment: you might also want to quote variable used in `sendemail` argument.

Answer (score 0):

1) use either `[ -d ...]` or `test -d ...` but **not** `test -d [ ... ]` (same goes for `-f` )

2) `test -f [ $file ]`

will

- look for a file named `[`
- complain about extra argument

3) in

```
if test [ -d  "$dir" ]
then 
    echo "Found directory /tmp/gotcha/" ]
else 
    mkdir /tmp/gotcha/
fi
```

you could use the `dir` var

```
if test  -d  "$dir" 
then 
    echo "Found directory $dir" ]
else 
    mkdir "$dir"
fi
```

Comment: That definitely helped clean it up a bit, but my main issue is in the second half, where the email isn't being sent and the file isn't being removed at the end of the script.

Comment: there is a syntax error in testing file (see point 1) and 2) above )

Comment: No need to test with `-d`, just use `mkdir -p "$dir"` or possibly `mkdir -p "$dir" || exit 1`.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to hunt down my (major) mistake. There's a lot I tried to clean up, and in the process I noticed the sendEmail script I was using was missing an option:

```
-o tls=yes
```

In the end the script works completely, and looks a lot more neat:

```
#!/bin/bash

##########
## variable key
file=/tmp/gotcha/pic.jpg
dir=/tmp/gotcha
SMTPFROM=xxxxx@xxxxx.com
SMTPTO=xxxxx@xxxxx.com
SMTPSERVER=smtp.googlemail.com:587
SMTPUSER=xxxxx@xxxxx.com
SMTPPASS=xxxxx
SUBJECT="Someone tried to access your computer while you were away."
MESSAGE="Someone tried to access your computer while you were away. Here's a photo!"

##########
## create directory if it doesn't exist
if test -d "$dir"
then
        echo "Found directory...";
else
        echo "Directory not found..."
        sleep 1.5
        echo "Creating directory $dir..."
        mkdir -p $dir
        sleep 1.5
        echo "Directory created...";
fi

##########
## ensures directory is clear before beginning script
if test -f "$file"
then 
        echo "Clearing directory of any past files..."
        sudo rm $file;
fi

##########
## takes picture with webcam if incorrect password is entered
## stores picture in created directory
ts=`date +%s`
ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -s vga -i /dev/video0 -vframes 1 $file
#exit 0  ## NOTE - must exit with status 0

##########
## send $file in email
sudo sendemail -f $SMTPFROM -t $SMTPTO -o tls=yes -a $file -u $SUBJECT -m $MESSAGE -s $SMTPSERVER -xu $SMTPUSER -xp $SMTPPASS

##########
```

Don't mind all the extra hashes, just my way of organizing. I'm sure there's a lot I could still be doing better, and a lot of unnecessary stuff, but it works! Thanks for all the input!